# What is the largest $i$ s.t. $p^i | (p^3-1)(p^3-p)(p^3-p^2)$ and why is it 3?

Tags: number-theory

What is the largest $i$ s.t.  $p^i | (p^3-1)(p^3-p)(p^3-p^2)$ and why is it 3?

I'm trying to figure out why $UT(3,Z_p)$ is a sylow p-subgroup of $GL(3,\mathbb{Z}_p)$, where $UT(3,Z_p)$ is the group of all upper $3x3$ upper triangular matrices over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ with $1$ along the diagonal. A simple combiniatorial arguement shows that $|GL(3,\mathbb{Z}_p)|=(p^3-1)(p^3-p)(p^3-p^2)$.

and obviously $|UT(3,Z_p)|=p^3$. So the result will follow if i can show this, although my elementary number theory is lacking so if somebody could explain this to me that'd be great.

Thanks!

Comment: $p\nmid(p^3-1)(p^2-1)(p-1)$.

Comment: hahaha thanks man wow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that
$$(p^3-1)(p^3-p)(p^3-p^2) = p^3(p^3-1)(p^2-1)(p-1)$$

For $0\leq i\leq3$ it is obvious that $p^i$ divides the above expression.

For $i>3$ we would require that $p | (p^3-1)(p^2-1)(p-1)$.

We can write
$$p^2-1 = (p-1)(p+1)$$
$$p^3-1 = (p-1)(p^2+p+1)$$

Because $p$ is odd (assuming that $p\neq2$), it follows that $(p-1)$ and $(p+1)$ are even, and therefore $p$ would need to divide $\frac{p-1}{2}$ or $\frac{p+1}{2}$, and it is obvious that it does not.

As for why $p$ doesn't divide $(p^2+p+1)$, that is because $p$ divides $(p^2+p)$, so it would need to divide $1$, which cannot be.